# Python error in mern installation

Tags: node.js, mern

I am php developer and now i want to build project with mern.io. and getting some errors in command line, can anyone help me to get out of these or let me know why these errors are showing up. I installed node.js,git and python.

I wrote the following commands.

```
npm install -g mern-cli
mern init your_new_app
cd your_new_app
npm install
```

Following errors are showing in cmd.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\JAVED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\mern\node_modules\nodejieba
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your system lacks the python, Kindly install python dependecy and then try to install the same. You may refer python installation procedure @ https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/

Comment: I also use  the following command 
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
That i get from the following link
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Python is installed successfully.But still i can not not install mern.

Comment: Did you added python env variable ? If not then please try to do it so.
You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

What version of python do you have?  I'm running into the exact same error and after some googling I found this https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1337

It seems node-gyp doesn't support python 3.  Unfortunately after reading through the entire thread, I couldn't find a solution other than downgrading to python 2.7